# Camera and gallery use in android crashes gallery app

Tags: android

Hi I have the below code for letting the use either capture the image or pick it from gallery. I capture an image save it and then try to pick an image from gallery the gallery app crashes always.

```
AlertDialog.Builder photoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        photoDialog
        .setTitle("Photo source")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Open Gallery",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        new Intent(                     Intent.ACTION_PICK,                                             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
                                        54);
}
})
.setNegativeButton("Open Camera",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
            fileName);
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
            .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,                                       values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(                                 MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,                                    mCapturedImageURI);

                                startActivityForResult(intent, 96);

                            }
                        });
        photoDialog.show();
```

LOGS

```
I/ActivityManager(  222): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/images/media cmp=com.cooliris.media/.Gallery } from pid 13631

I/SiteInspection(13631): In SiteInspectionDetailsActivity.onSaveInstanceState() .......

I/ActivityManager(  222): Start proc com.cooliris.media for activity com.cooliris.media/.Gallery: pid=13685 uid=10028 gids={1015, 3003}

W/InputManagerService(  222): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4091f7c8

D/BackgroundDataSender(13631): BackgroundDataService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): BackgroundLogService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): true

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): logsender ted

I/ActivityThread(13685): Pub com.cooliris.picasa.contentprovider: com.cooliris.picasa.PicasaContentProvider

I/Gallery (13685): onCreate

D/CacheService(13685): Refreshing Cache for all items

I/CacheService(13685): Refreshing cache.

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Building albums.

I/ActivityManager(  222): Displayed com.cooliris.media/.Gallery: +659ms

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Done building albums.

I/CacheService(13685): Building items.

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Done building items.

I/RenderView(13685): First Draw

I/MediaFeed(13685): Replacing media set -1595679508

I/MediaFeed(13685): Replacing media set 1506676782

D/CacheService(13685): Refreshing Cache for all items

I/CacheService(13685): Refreshing cache.

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Building albums.

W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13631): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Done building albums.

I/CacheService(13685): Building items.

D/BackgroundDataSender(13631): BackgroundDataService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): BackgroundLogService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): true

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): logsender ted

E/DiskCache(13685): Unable to create or tempFile /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/local-album-cache

I/CacheService(13685): Done building items.

I/GridLayer(13685): Slot changing from -1 to -1

D/BackgroundDataSender(13631): BackgroundDataService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): BackgroundLogService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): true

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): logsender ted

D/BackgroundDataSender(13631): BackgroundDataService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): BackgroundLogService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): true

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): logsender ted

D/wpa_supplicant(  456): wpa_supplicant_scan: scan_req = 0, ap_scan = 1

D/wpa_supplicant(  456): Starting AP scan (broadcast SSID)

D/wpa_supplicant(  456): wpa_driver_wext_scan: specific scan = 0

D/wpa_supplicant(  456): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds

I/GridLayer(13685): Slot changing from 0 to 0

I/RenderView(13685): Texture creation fail, glError 1281

D/BackgroundDataSender(13631): BackgroundDataService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): BackgroundLogService started

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): true

D/BackgroundLogSender(13631): logsender ted

I/CacheService(13685): Built thumbnail and screennail for 19 in 628

W/dalvikvm(13685): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

E/AndroidRuntime(13685): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 13

E/AndroidRuntime(13685): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(13685):    at com.cooliris.media.GridDrawManager.drawBlendedComponents(GridDrawManager.java:716)

E/AndroidRuntime(13685):    at com.cooliris.media.GridLayer.renderBlended(GridLayer.java:831)

E/AndroidRuntime(13685):    at com.cooliris.media.RenderView.onDrawFrame(RenderView.java:684)

E/AndroidRuntime(13685):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1363)

E/AndroidRuntime(13685):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)

I/RenderView(13685): OnPause RenderView com.cooliris.media.RenderView@40578d58

W/ActivityManager(  222):   Force finishing activity com.cooliris.media/.Gallery
```

Comment: can you post your logcat..

Comment: I have posted the logcat. I have also tried boradcasting intent Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE even then it crashes

Comment: the problem is here: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.cooliris.media.GridDrawManager.drawBlendedComponents(GridDrawManager.java:716)

Comment: How can I over come that ? It is 100% reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

and in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){  

            Uri picUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer thinking it works. But it crashed again. This happens only on phone with 2.3 Android version.

Comment: Same error at the same point. I first capture image save and then try to pick an image from gallary, it crashes.

Comment: Could some one help with this please?